# Implicit system calls in UNIX commands

Tags: linux, bash, unix, posix

I've been studying UNIX and system calls and I came across a low-level and tricky questions. The question asks what system calls are called for this command:

`grep word1 word2 > file.txt`

I did some research and I was unable to find a huge number of resources on the underlying UNIX calls. However, it seems to me that the answer would be `open` (to open and the file descriptor for the file `file.txt`), then `dup2` (to change the `STDOUT` of `grep` to the file descriptor of `open`), then `write` to write the `STDOUT` of `grep` (which is now the file descriptor of `file.txt`), and finally `close()`, to close the file descriptor of `file.txt`... However, I have no idea if I am right or on the correct path, can anyone with experience in UNIX enlighten me on this topic?

Comment: I hope you find the answer to your question here, but you may find [this stack](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) better suited to answer it. Best of luck!

Comment: You can have a look at the [source code of GNU grep](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git).

Comment: `STDOUT` redirection is done by the shell, `grep` doesn't even know that a redirection is happening, that's completely transparent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on correct direction in your research. This command is very helpful to trace system calls in any program:

[strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace)

On my PC it shows output (without stream redirection):

```
$ strace grep abc ss.txt
execve("/bin/grep", ["grep", "abc", "ss.txt"], [/* 237 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x13de000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1785694000
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
stat("ss.txt", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=13, ...}) = 0
open("ss.txt", O_RDONLY)                = 3
ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0x7fffa0e4f370) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
read(3, "abc\n123\n321\n\n", 32768)     = 13
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 2), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f178568c000
write(1, "abc\n", 4abc
)                    = 4
read(3, "", 32768)                      = 0
close(3)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f178568c000, 4096)            = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

Comment: But that is a Linux specific tool. For Unix in general you normally can use `dtrace` though. (Which I think will also be ported to Linux soon.)

Comment: @DavidOngaro: Claiming `dtrace` is normal for Unix would be an exaggeration, I think.  You can use `dtrace` on Solaris (though `truss` was simpler to user); a variant of `dtrace` exists on Mac; but other systems (HP-UX, AIX, …) use other commands (than `dtrace` or `strace` or `truss`).